# Is mathematical sectioning bad style in questions

Tags: discussion

I like the mathematical tradition of setting up a problem with with the following structure:

Summary

Definition

Question: is theorem below true?

Theorem

etc.

Someone told me that this is bad style asking questions here. Is it?

As an example we can take my try of a question here [maximal principle uniform covering of a sphere with uniform geodesics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2316201/453800?sgp=2)

Comment: If you cover all the steps you list above, with any question, and change the last (etc.) into the heading: **Context** (Where this question arose for me?  My thoughts on whether the theorem is true or not, and the attempts I've made or the approaches I might make to prove it's true, or prove it's false, etc...)

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to ask whether a theorem is true. If it's a theorem, then by definition of theorem it's true. Do you mean to ask whether an assertion, or a conjecture, is true?

Comment: Gerry good point. I make a conjecture.

Comment: I did not downvote your question, but I think it's too long. Walls of text are not very motivating for readers like me.

Comment: Sorry for beeing so clumsy at formulating stuff. I reworked it again and it looks much shorter and better now.

Comment: The section name *"Executive Summary"* in the linked question sounds a bit silly. This management speak has a [specific meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/357632) which I think has no place in mathematical literature.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I was just tired by complaints that it was too mathematical from a bunch of others and it's actually a try to joke them a little.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not bad style to structure a post like this. In general, one should however try to be concise; that is, don't write a page of text before coming forward with your actual point, etc.

I could not find the specific remark you reference. Yet, I would venture to guess that the main cause of problems you might have faced with your post was not due to this structuring.

Comment: It was a comment not from this site I would say so not any fault on the people here. He was just trying to help and looked how other questions was formulated here.

Comment: The question earlier had bugs and information that was unesesary. I'm rosty when it comes to measure theory and proper mathematical formulation rigor and just recently rewrote it after a long walk. I think it is much better now.